# How can I mirror a group of components and wires across a line in eagle, without having it switch board sides?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, mirror

I want to design a board that is symmetrical - I have designed the left side, and now I want to copy the components and wires to the right side such that it is "mirrored" across the center line - what is the best way to accomplish this in eagle?

here is a screenshot of what I am working with:
[image]

I want to take the components inside the orange box and mirror them across the teal line, such that I can then re-incorporate them into the PCB on the left

Comment: maybe the term you want is rotate or flip, not "mirror" because "Mirror" can mean to the other side of the board

Comment: also, Eagle may not be able to offer such an action/result but I know that Altium PCB designer can.

Comment: @KyranF it's not rotate, as I can do that, and one could make an argument that you are "flipping" to the other side of the PCB when you do what the normal "mirror does" - I think mirror is the correct term, just that it is across a plane that is not the PCB in this case

Comment: no flipping can be around a horizontal or vertical line, and depending on the terminology (which is not consistent, and neither is the use of "Mirror") it can assume that it stays on the front-facing layer of the PCB

Comment: if i had the options, i would rotate your block there by 180 degrees and then flip/mirror around a horizontal line to make it line up with your other side. See the Eagle command line functions maybe there is one hidden in there that the UI doesn't easily expose

Comment: this does not seem to help though: http://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/59.htm

Comment: What is the chip marked "DRV"? Because for most chips, mirroring the footprint while keeping it on the same layer will result in wrong connections.

Comment: I agree with @ThePhoton - what you are asking to do makes no sense - the "mirrored" chip will have a pin-out on the copper that doesn't match the chip.

Comment: @ThePhoton your right, I will need to re-route some of the wires, but that is a minor change - I am mostly interested in the physical positioning of the pieces. To answer the question though, it's a ti [DRV8871](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8871.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.

At best you could position the components on the right side symmetrically about the cyan line relative to their counterparts on the left.  However, the components themselves can't be mirrored.  This only works for symmetrical parts, like resistors for example.  It's not going to work for whatever the 8-pin chip is since you can't magically mirror its pinout.

Comment: How would I do the "at best" scenario where I position them symmetrically? (or lets to pretend that it's a resistor array with identical values)

Comment: @user: I'd probably write a program that generates a script to place all the components on the left side.  You keep deleting the components, tweaking the program, and trying again until things are where you want them to be.  Then you flip the X coordinates about some value.